# How to take best action instead of taking random action

Tags: python, python-3.x, reinforcement-learning

My agent keeps taking a random action, so the algorithm is not training properly. How do I ensure it takes the best action which is stored in the line "next_action, ArgMax = custom_argmax(Q_value)". The function custom_argmax computes the maximum Q value found for each state, action pair.

```
max_episodes = 10
max_steps_per_episode = 1000

discount_rate = 0.99
exploration_rate = 0.5
max_exploration_rate = 1
min_exploration_rate = 0.1
learning_rate = 0.01
explore_decay_rate = 0.2
errors = []


def play_single_game(max_steps_per_episode, render):
    global errors

    state = env.reset()
    # print('We are resetting: ' )

    action = env.action_space.sample()

    for step in range(max_steps_per_episode - 1):

        # if episode == max_episodes - 1:
        if render:
            env.render()

        # print("This is the Ac:",  a)
        '''
        if step%2 == 0:
            a = 1
        else:
            a = 1
        '''
        new_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)  # declare all, gets new state from taking certain action
        # print(info)
        next_state = new_state
        # print(reward)
        old_weights = weights.theta.copy()

        if done == True:
            weights.theta += learning_rate * (reward - weights_multiplied_by_features(state, action)) * feature_space(state, action)
            # print("we are done")
            break
        else:
            # not finished
            Q_value= associated_Q_value(next_state)

            exploration_rate_threshold = random.uniform(0, 1)

            next_action, ArgMax = custom_argmax(Q_value)  # is best action

            if exploration_rate_threshold < exploration_rate:  # take random

                r = random.randint(0, len(LEGAL_MOVES) - 1)

                next_action = r

            # we will update Q(s,a) AS we experience the episode
            weights.theta += learning_rate * (reward + discount_rate * ArgMax - weights_multiplied_by_features(state, action)) * feature_space(state, action)

            # next state becomes current state
            state = next_state
            action = next_action

            change_in_weights = np.abs(weights.theta - old_weights).sum()
            errors.append(change_in_weights)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing epsilon-greedy exploration. You have set `exploration_rate = 0.5` so your agent will always take 50% random actions, obviously. This is probably too high, but it doesn't mean that your agent is not learning.

If you want to properly evaluate your agent you have to run an episode with exploration disabled. You cannot just disable random actions, because then it may never try different actions; it's called the exploration/exploitation trade-off. You could, however, slowly dial down exploration as the agent is learning, e.g. with `exploration_rate *= 0.999` in your loop, or similar.